# Log file name with time does not work correctly

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to implement an asynchronous logs system with rotation by size and intervals following the log4j documentation.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

This is the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My config:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="FooLog" fileName="${path}/foo.log" 
    filePattern="${path}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/foo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false">

    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>|%d|%p|%c{1.}|[%t]|%m|%ex%n</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>

    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="${interval}" modulate="true" />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${fileSize}" />
    </Policies>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

And my result is the files:

> log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-17-1.log.gz
>
> log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-17-2.log.gz
>
> log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-17-3.log.gz
>
> log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-17-4.log.gz
>
> log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-17-5.log.gz

My local time is **2018-04-04 15:11:38,724** (Written in the content of the log).
The name of the log files should be: log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-15-n.log.gz

I'm using a fileSize=10 KB and interval=6 for these tests. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

the problem is the interval value, in this case 6, add the value to the time of the file name. How can I fix this and continue with the rotation for hours?

**SOLUTION:**

I have solved my problem by changing TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy by CronTriggeringPolicy with a value to write the files every three hours. In this way the name of the file with the time is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause might be that the logger uses a different timezone.

Let's assume you want the timezone to be UTC.

You can try to force the logger to use a specific timezone.

```
filePattern="${path}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/foo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}{UTC}-%i.log.gz"
```

Note the addition of {UTC} in the above snippet. You need to replace UTC with the timezone of your choice.

**Update based on comment**

Since GMT + 1 timezone is desired the following can be used.

```
filePattern="${path}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/foo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}{GMT+1}-%i.log.gz"
```

For more info one can see the **d{pattern} - date{pattern}** row in the table of the documentation [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout).
According to that "You can also use a set of braces containing a time zone id per `java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone`. If no date format specifier is given then the DEFAULT format is used. "

Comment: This worked for me, but in my case I have to add  "{GMT + 1}"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer to unclude this also.

Comment: Today I have validated that it does not work correctly. It is not the fault of the format of the date, it is the problem of the interval value, in this case 6, add the value to the time of the file name.

Comment: Perhaps you need to rephrase the description of the question, since from the following:

"log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-17-5.log.gz
My local time is 2018-04-04 15:11:38,724 (Written in the content of the log). 
The name of the log files should be: log\2018-04-04\foo-2018-04-04-15-n.log.gz"
It seems that the hour was the problem, so this answer aimed at answering that part.